# Realiza el update pero no marca el mensaje de realizado

Tags: mysql, bootstrap

Este es el código que estoy usando, cabe destacar que lo uso para **insert** y me funciona al 100%, pero al cambiar el **insert por update**, me lo realiza pero no me marca el echo luego de ejecutarlo. Ayuda

Deseo que al momento de presionar el boton guardar, este me envie el mensaje si lo realizo o no, y luego lo lleve al inicio o a otro url para poder realizar otro formulario dentro de la misma pantalla donde se ubica la persona.

> Pregunto.. hice mal al usar el mismo codigo de insert en update?, tiene que ver algo o es otra sintaxis al momento de mostrar el mensaje en dicho update?.

De ante mano muchas gracias el que pueda ayudarme con esta incognita. jejeje

````
<?php 

include("config/con_db.php");

if (isset($_POST['register'])) {
    if (strlen($_POST['id_alicuota']) >= 1){
        $id_alicuota = trim($_POST['id_alicuota']);
        $id_alicuota1 = trim($_POST['id_alicuota1']);
        $id_alicuota2 = trim($_POST['id_alicuota2']);
    $id_alicuota3 = trim($_POST['id_alicuota3']);
    $id_alicuota4 = trim($_POST['id_alicuota4']);
    $id_alicuota5 = trim($_POST['id_alicuota5']);
    $id_alicuota6 = trim($_POST['id_alicuota6']);
    $id_usuario = $_SESSION['id_usuario'];```
    
     ```   $consulta = "UPDATE administrador SET id_alicuota='".$id_alicuota."', id_alicuota1='".$id_alicuota1."', id_alicuota2='".$id_alicuota2."', id_alicuota3='".$id_alicuota3."', id_alicuota4='".$id_alicuota4."', id_alicuota5='".$id_alicuota5."', id_alicuota6='".$id_alicuota6."' WHERE id_usuario='".$id_usuario."'";
        $resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);
        if ($resultado) {
            ?><hr>
            <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                      <strong>¡Actividad economica actualizada correctamente!</strong>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
           <?php
        } else {
            ?><hr>
                <div class="alert alert-danger alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                      <strong>¡Ups ha ocurrido un error, vuelve a intentar!</strong>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>
           <?php
        }
    }   else {
            ?><hr>
                <div class="alert alert-warning alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                      <strong>¡Por favor, complete los campos!</strong>
                      <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                      </button>
                    </div>          
           <?php
    }
    
}

?>```
````

Comment: 1) Te arroja algún mensaje, y 2) Los registros se llegan a actualizar?

Comment: No arroja ningun mensaje, solo vuelve a refrescar la pagina y si realiza el registro. si se actualiza.

Comment: Si tu código hace el `Update` pero no entra en el `If`, puede ser porque tu código está algo confuso, supongo que lo publicado no es el código completo. Te sugiero que las secciones **PHP** tengan el inicio `<?php`  y el fin `?>` definidos.

Comment: Si es el codigo completo

Comment: Haz un `echo $consulta;die();` antes de `$resultado = mysqli_query($conex,$consulta);` para que te muestre la consulta completa y ejecutala en el phpmyadmin o via mysql en la shell, para ver que te devuelve y si esta bien.  A simple vista todo parece correcto, asi que mira de ir depurando paso a paso.